# How to create a Swiper JS, HTML CSS Carousel with blurred non focused elements?

Tags: javascript, carousel, swiper.js

I'm trying to reproduce this piece of design for the web.

[image]
but I'm not sure what's the best solution to achieve this goal. I need to develop it inside WordPress. I tried a good solution for other carousel sliders with the swiper.js library. But I'm not getting there with this actual design since I'm not able to displace the 3 elements together and at the same time and blur the non active elements...

This is the code I've right now (for the background I'll take care directly inside the wordpress div)

```html
<!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .swiper-slide {
      cursor: pointer;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: transparent;

      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: column;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }


    .testosotto {
      margin-top: -15px;
      color:white;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 15px;
      line-height: 22px;
      text-align: center;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://www.beyconsulting.it/Factanza/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/3.png" /><p class="testosotto">Guarda i nostri video</p></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://www.beyconsulting.it/Factanza/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/2.png" /><p class="testosotto">Leggi i nostri Articoli</p></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://www.beyconsulting.it/Factanza/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/1.png" /><p class="testosotto">Ascolta i nostri Podcast</p></div>

    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <!--<div class="swiper-button-next"></div> -->
    <!--<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div> -->
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 5,
      loop: true,
      loopFillGroupWithBlank: false,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '',
        prevEl: '',
      },
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it like this thanks

```
.swiper-slide {
  filter: blur(4px);
}

.swiper-slide-active {
  filter: blur(0);
}
```

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  centeredSlides: true,
  spaceBetween: 220,
  slidesPerGroup: 1,
  loop: true,
  loopFillGroupWithBlank: false,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '',
    prevEl: '',
  },
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #33f;
}

.swiper-slide {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: transparent;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide {
  filter: blur(4px);
}

.swiper-slide-active {
  filter: blur(0);
}

.testosotto {
  margin-top: -15px;
  color: white;
  width: 110px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  //wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css">
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://www.beyconsulting.it/Factanza/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/3.png" />
      <p class="testosotto">Guarda i nostri video</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://www.beyconsulting.it/Factanza/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/2.png" />
      <p class="testosotto">Leggi i nostri Articoli</p>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://www.beyconsulting.it/Factanza/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/1.png" />
      <p class="testosotto">Ascolta i nostri Podcast</p>
    </div>


  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <!--<div class="swiper-button-next"></div> -->
  <!--<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div> -->
</div>

<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try with `filter: blur(value);` in css

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer, the problem is that I'm not able to display all the elements in the same view and at the same time having pagination on the bottom to move between the three of them.

Comment: So you have to form your question better cause it's not really blur related, but more about aligning stuff.

Comment: Ok, I tried to formulate better the question. The thing is not just related to blur but also to how to display all the 3 elements inside the same view keeping the focused one blurred

Answer (score -1):

This works well, though the blur was a bit abrupt with a larger blur and a 1s Swiper speed. In my case, I also used a transition to match the speed:

```
.swiper-slide {
    filter: blur(40px);
    transition: 1s filter linear;
}

.swiper-slide-active {
    filter: blur(0);
}
```